# How to get all node entities tagged with a specific term?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

For a given taxonomy term in D8, is there any API function/method that returns all node entities that reference it?

Answer (score 19):

You can use `loadByProperties()` to get all node entities that reference `$term_id`:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties([
  'field_tags' => $term_id,
]);
```

Comment: not working for drupal 8

Comment: works well for drupal 8.9

Answer (score 11):

Easiest way I think is to query database `taxonomy_index` table keeps record of what node is tagged with what term

```
function _get_nodes_by_term($term_id) {
  $query = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_index', 'ti');
  $query->fields('ti', ['nid']);
  $query->condition('ti.tid', $term_id);
  $nodes = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
  return $nodes;
}

dpm(_get_nodes_by_term(<term_id>));
```

Drupal Core does it by views.
Out the box term page display is created by views so if you visit `admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term`, this view is responsible to show all tagged content by given term, which is essentially running database query.

Comment: Best solution, but I think it should be `$nodes = $query->execute()->fetchAll();`

Comment: One thing to be aware of with this approach is that it will only get published nodes

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple term ids you can pass an array of the ids instead of just a  single value.

```
$term_ids =  array (1,2,3);
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties([
  'field_tags' => $term_ids,
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If your nodes not having revision then this code will work, by default it will return the first revision

```
  $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery()
 ->condition('field_tags', $termId)
 ->execute();
```

**If your nodes have multiple revisions,  To get the nodes by  the latest tagged revision. you need to use the following code**

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery()
->latestRevision()
->condition('field_tags', $termId, '=')
->execute();
```

***if you have multiple values then you can use array***

```
 $termIds = [3,56,456];
 $nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery()
 ->latestRevision()
 ->condition('field_tags', $termIds)
 ->execute();
```