# How can I limit the exposed filters to only display values for which content exists?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

We have a view for the *Basic page* content type, which has a *Category* field that allows to enter multiple values.
All values for *Category* are displayed (*IoT*, *Cloud*, *Security*), but there are only nodes that use *IoT* and *Cloud*. I want to display only *IoT* and *Cloud* for the *Category* exposed filter.

How can I limit the exposed filters to only display values for which content exists?

The view settings are the following.

Format

- Show: Content | Teaser
- Format: Unformatted List | Settings

Filter Criteria

- Authored on (exposed)
- Category (field_category) (exposed) | Settings (settings is set to Category tag, selection type = Dropdown)
- Author (exposed)
- Published (= Yes)
- Content Type (= Basic Page)

Sort Criteria

- Content: Authored on (desc)

Contextual Filters, Relationship

- None

Exposed form

- Exposed form style: Better Exposed Filters | Settings
- Settings are set to default in Better Exposed Filters

Other

- Use Ajax: Yes
- Use aggregation: no
- query settings: default settings

Here is what we tried. This only gets me the nodes that have a value for `field_category` and all term values for `categories` term individually.

```
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $node_storage = Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('node');
  $node_ids = $node_storage->getQuery();

  // This returns all nodes with a value for *field_category*. 
  $nodes = $node_ids->condition('type','page')
    ->exists('field_category')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->sort('title')
    ->execute();

  // returns all taxonomy terms. 
  $category_tree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('categories');

}
```

Comment: See [Change filter value in Views programmatically in hook](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-04-27/change-filter-value-in-views). Basically you will want to query the DB to see if there is at least 1 result  for each category and then override the filter based on that.

Comment: @NoSssweat using the link i updated the question with the code I tried, but still cannot get the list i need. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['tid']['#options'])) {
    foreach ($form['tid']['#options'] as $key => $value) {
      // Limit to numeric keys to exclude the 'All' option.
      if (is_numeric($key)) {
        // Start database query.
        $query = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_index', 'ti');
        $query->fields('ti', ['nid']);
        $query->condition('ti.tid', $key);
        $nodes = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
        // Remove option if term has no instance.
        if (!$nodes) {
          unset($form['tid']['#options'][$key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will probably need to adjust the 'tid' in $form['tid']['#options'] to the Filter identifier as defined in your views' filter settings.
Credits for the quick and efficient database query go to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219368/25154.

Comment: Instead of adding the `database query` inside the `foreach`, I retrieved all the `nid` first, then I queried outside of the `foreach` all of the terms I needed, and inside the `foreach` I was able to filter out and use `unset` as you have based on an `if` condition. This answer led to that solution so marking it as such.

Comment: How would you further limit this list so only nodes of X content type are associated?