# Limit views exposed filter options to terms with associated nodes of content type X

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a module which limits the options in a views exposed filter to terms which have associated nodes. The code is based on this answer: [How can I limit the exposed filters to only display values for which content exists?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274508/how-can-i-limit-the-exposed-filters-to-only-display-values-for-which-content-exi)

**Code:**

```
if (isset($form['area-of-law']['#options'])) {

  foreach ($form['area-of-law']['#options'] as $key => $value) {

    if (is_numeric($key)) {
      $query = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_index', 'ti');
      $query->fields('ti', ['nid']);
      $query->condition('ti.tid', $key);
      $nodes = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();

      if (!$nodes) {
        unset($form['area-of-law']['#options'][$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but all node types are returned. I would like to limit the filter further to only show those of content type X.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $query = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_index', 'ti');
  $query->condition('ti.tid', $key);
  $query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = ti.nid'); // join node table
  $query->condition('n.type', 'x'); // filter by type
  $query->fields('n', ['nid']); // add filtered nids
  $nodes = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

Comment: Thank you @no-sssweat. The code is working except the returned TIDs are out by one so 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 not 1, 2, 3, 4, 6. Exposed field has depth so TIDs 2, 3, 4 and 6 are children of 1… could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Sorry not on my PC, try moving the `join` line before first condition and if still same try changing `fields` to `ti` instead of `n`.

Comment: Still not working, unfortunately.

Comment: `TIDs are out by one` You mean NIDs, you're retrieving NIDs. Are you sure the Node IDs you're getting back do not belong to content type X?

Comment: Your code is filtering the exposed filter list to only show terms that have associated nodes however, the list option values (TIDs) are out by one. Screenshot here: https://digitaldots.co.uk/exposed-filter-options.png – the values should be 2, 3, 4, 6.

Comment: `however, the list option values (TIDs) are out by one` Is my code responsible for the list options?

Comment: Yes, the query is filtering the exposed filter list options.